# How to define Json schema validator for Map<String, Object>

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

Can someone please help me defining Json Schema validator for the below Json.

```
{
  "WorkflowName1": {
    "WorkflowName": "WorkflowName1",
    "NumberOfWorkers": 1,
    "ActivityConfigs": {
      "ActivityName1": {
        "ActivityName": "ActivityName1",
        "MaxTime": 200
      }
    }
  },
  "WorkflowName2": {
    "WorkflowName": "WorkflowName2",
    "NumberOfWorkers": 10,
    "ActivityConfigs": {
      "ActivityName1": {
        "ActivityName": "ActivityName2",
        "MaxTime": 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, above Json is a `Map<String, WorkflowConfig>`.

WorkflowConfig has `WorkflowName`, `NumberOfWorkers` and `Map<String, ActivityConfigs>`. Among these `WorkflowName` and `NumberOfWorkers` are mandatory, and `Map<String, ActivityConfigs>` is optional.

ActivityConfig has `ActivityName` and `MaxTime` both required.

I want to define Json schema for the above structure for schemaType: `http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The structure is a little bit redundant. Maybe, serialize the map as an array of WorkflowConfig objects as it also contains the names?

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below schema. And you can also try it in online [json
schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/T3IKwkVu)

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "WorkflowName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "NumberOfWorkers": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "ActivityConfigs": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/configDef"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "WorkflowName",
            "NumberOfWorkers"
        ]
    },
    "definitions": {
        "configDef": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "ActivityName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MaxTime": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "ActivityName",
                    "MaxTime"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm using `additionalProperties` because `Map<String, WorkflowConfig>` in this key name is not fixed it may be anything.

Comment: May I know why this define a MAP? as map contains key-value but seemed the above json schema only contains value.

Comment: It contains both, we mention allowed keys inside the properties object, and for the value we only mention the type of value allowed, and if it is an object we can use definitions to validate that